# Developing and deploying Angular 2 application with Java REST back-end to production

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, jenkins

I have an application with a Java REST (Jetty/Jersey) back-end. I want to develop a UI in Angular 2. How do I best structure and build the project(s) for development and deployment? Some considerations:

1. I like using Node and npm start to run a test server. It would be fine to start both Java service and do npm start for testing.
2. We use Eclipse for the Java app. Minimal editing in Eclipse for Typescript with Angelozerr's plugin works great.
3. We use Jenkins for the build.

I'm attempting to figure out:

1. Folder structure. Does it go inside the same Eclipse project as the REST service?
2. Build. Simply do npm install in Jenkins to build and populate the dist folder?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial may be helpful:

https://blog.udemy.com/node-js-tutorial/

It covers AngularJS, NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. (MEAN stack)

Answer (score 0):

As I've built the same kind of thing a couple of times now, I would recommend building each layer as separate projects.  It can be done as a single project, but these are really separate concerns, and both applications become a little simpler if you separate them.  It even gives you the flexibility of deploying them to separate boxes.